# *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated. Any Solutions?

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out what is causing this problem. I am on a virtual machine with Ubuntu and using Geany to code. Everything should be right however, it still pops up, so do I run out of memory or is the buffer overloaded? Does anyone have an idea? Would greatly appreciate any feedback.
Would it be safe to bypass GCC stack smashing detection? Thank you in advance.

```c
#define MAX_STR 40

void ProcessPerson(char entry[]);
int main(void)
{
    char data[][MAX_STR] = {"Maria,Kask",
                            "Johanna-Maria,Kask",
                            "Kalev Kristjan,Kuusk"};
    int i;
    int numOfPeople = sizeof(data) / MAX_STR;

    printf("Number of people: %d\n\n", numOfPeople);
    for (i = 0; i < numOfPeople; i++)
    {
        ProcessPerson(data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

    void ProcessPerson(char entry[])
    {
    int i, j;
    char str[2][4] = {""};

    printf("Processing line: '%s'\n", entry);
   

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 4)
        {
            str[0][j] = entry[j];

            j++;
        }

        if (entry[i] == ',')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    str[0][strlen(str[0]) - 1] = '\0';  

    j = 0;
    i++;
    while (j < 4)
    {
        str[1][j] = entry[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    str[1][strlen(str[1]) - 2] = '\0';
    str[0][0] = str[0][0] + 32;
    str[1][0] = str[1][0] + 32;

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        if (entry[i] == ',')
        {
            entry[i] = ' ';
            break;
        }
    }

    char email[14] = " ";
    strcat(email, str[0]);
    strcat(email, str[1]);
    strcat(email, "@ttu.ee");   

    printf("Nimi: %s\n", entry);
    printf("E-post:%s\n\n", email);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is supposed to do? This is doing a lot of complex indirect addressing, and I'm not sure this needs to be this complicated.

Comment: The program's job is to generate an email address for students using the first 3 letters of their name and the first 3 letters of their last name. Then add the domain to it, and print out their names and email. I have been learning programming for 2 months so I apologize for bad code and even worse formatting.

Comment: Formatting is ok, but you need to give us a [mre]

Comment: Sorry, I already did my best to take out everything that does not interact with the problem. I am not smart enough to be able to minimize the code and make sure that the same problem with the same conditions happens.

Comment: "Stack smashing" occurs when a function modifies data on the stack, prior to the beginning of its own stack frame.  This can sometimes be detected, usually after the fact when the function returns.  It typically results from overrunning the bounds of a stack-allocated object.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    str[1][strlen(str[1]) - 2] = '\0';
> ```

You didn't null terminate `str[1]`, hence you can't sensibly call `strlen(str[1])`. What's more, there's not even room in `str` for the terminating null character after copying four characters into `str[1]`.

Comment: Thank you sir for the info. It appears that was the root of the problem. I believe after changing some things I will get it to work. Thank you again.